# Contradiction between OEIS and factordb.com

Tags: prime-numbers, oeis, primorial

[OEIS A014545](https://oeis.org/A014545) says 1+13494## is a prime number but [factordb.com](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000000576058963) says it is composite, where n## is the product of first n primes on factordb. Which is correct?

edit:
Sorry if my question is not appropriate here. I found some small prime numbers of the form 1+n##, and looked them up in OEIS to find this number. Then I also looked it up in factordb and found that it says not a prime. I wondered if there was a mistake in the OEIS or factordb, so I asked this question. I want to know whether factordb or OEIS is correct.

Comment: Have you performed a Rabin-Miller primality test?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and in particular do explain why you are interested in this number.

Comment: @user21820 I disagree. The question is both interesting and motivated It is clearly explained why the author is interested in this particular number.

Comment: If I remember right, factordb had some problems with "##". This could explain the error.

Comment: I suggest to report this error in the mersenne-forum.

Comment: @Peter: No, it is **not** clearly explained. Why focus on this number, among lots of possible discrepancies between lists found online?

Comment: @user21820 Maybe this is the first discrepancy that hgut found? Certainly this is the first that I recall. I think the relevance of this question is justified.

Comment: errors in factordb are rare to my experience, so it is very unlkely that the author found a bunch of discrepancies of which he/she just randomly picked out one case. And to report errors to improve factordb can be nothing bad !

Comment: @supinf: I'm not saying the relevance of this question is unjustified. Do you see a close-vote from me? No. And I have not even downvoted. On the other hand, your comment justifies my claim that the context is **unclear**; you can only guess, and can't know why hgut had this question.

Comment: @user21820 I do not get this logic. The author (probably by chance) discovered a discrepancy between two (more or less) reliable sources and wondered which is true. Isn't that enough context ? Whether you consider the question interesting and/or useful is another story.

Comment: @Peter: How did the asker discover this discrepancy? The very fact that you are forced to say "probably by chance" shows clearly that the question is lacking in context as I claimed.

Answer (score 4):

Accoridng to PFGW, the number is $3$-PRP. This does not prove the primality but chances stand very good.

```
PFGW Version 4.0.1.64BIT.20191203.Win_Dev [GWNUM 29.8]

145823#+1 is 3-PRP! (120.3835s+0.0233s)

Done.
```

This number can be proven prime with the p-1-method. Perhaps someone does this.

UPDATE : The number passed a miller rabin test with $5$ random bases.

Comment: what does 3-PRP mean?

Comment: It passes the weak Fermat test with base $3$

Comment: Isn't it possible to perform the p-1 method with PFGW?

Comment: I know I'm late to point this out, but the Question involves the *twice* primorial $1+13494##$, not $1+145823#$.  But your Comment on the Question shows you were aware of the double primorial aspect.